# Multiple Routing in Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web API 2, I want to route using parameters such as (name & id).

When I try this :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "IDApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "NameApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I got the route **'api/customer/getByID/5'** worked fine.

But the route **'api/customer/searchByName/fawzy'** didn't work.

And if I set the **NameAPI** route before the **IDAPI** route the result is the opposite.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by a combination of **Pattern & Route Attribute**

In the **WebAPIConfig** file :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "IDApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^[0-9]+$" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: null
       );
```

In the **Controller** :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/customer/search/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult Search(string name)
{

}

[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute `[Route("api/customer/searchByName/{name}")]` from namespace `System.Web.Http.Routing` for `searchByName` action.

Comment: i know that, but still not comfortable to set all of my action's routes manually, i want to set it as a **pattern**

Comment: I think RoutePrefix and Route attributes best way for customizing routes.